# JAR file in tomcat/lib cannot log using log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Aloha All,

I have a JAR that is shared by multiple web apps.  It must be in Tomcat/lib because it creates in memory objects that are shared by multiple WAR files.  (I did not design this BTW.)  This is why it is not included in each WAR.

Long story short I'd like to be able to log from this JAR file to log4j.  I have it included as a maven dependency and it is not logging when deployed in Tomcat.

I tried using a log4j.properties in the JAR, in Tomcat, etc with no luck.  I also tried hard coding a config in a class:

/**
     * Get a logger instance to use and configure it since its not getting done
     * via Tomcat's settngs:
     */
    private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(RoomRatePlan.class);

```
static {
    ConsoleAppender ca = new ConsoleAppender();
    ca.setWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
    ca.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%5p %d [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n"));
    LOGGER.addAppender(ca);
}
```

and even this does not produce log output.  Any ideas?

Comment: do you have log4j jar under tomcat lib directory or is it under your war file lib derectory

Comment: I have log4j-xxxxx.jar under /tomcat/lib/

Comment: i have the same problem, the only solution for now it's using system.out.println and see the results in the catalina.out